# Using Bypass to parse Markdown in Android, not working with Images

Tags: android, markdown

I'm using bypass lib to parse a markdown string to show inside a TextView.
What basically this lib does is to parse all strings and build an SpannedString to show this inside a TextView. I've debuged all the lib code and aren't able to find what is doing wrong in a reasonable time. Is there someone that have been faced the same problem and can help me?

```
String markdownStr = "# Testing Markdown\n" +
        "\n" +
        "![surf](http://www.adesl.pt/images/outras-provas/surf.jpg)";

TextView markdownTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.markdown);

Bypass bypass = new Bypass(getApplicationContext());

CharSequence charSequence = bypass.markdownToSpannable(markdownStr, new Bypass.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

        //TODO: get drawable from source

        Drawable drawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);

        return drawable;
    }
});

markdownTxtView.setText(charSequence);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding bellow code it works:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Picasso Image Getter 
https://github.com/Commit451/BypassPicassoImageGetter

Glide Image Getter
https://github.com/victorlaerte/BypassGlideImageGetter